# Understanding GPU Allocation on TF

Tags: memory-management, tensorflow, gpu

I was doing the tutorial *A Guide to TF Layers: Building a Convolutional Neural Network* and got a

> Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[10000,32,28,28]

during evaluate phase. Since my GPU is a GeForce GTX 680 with only 2GB memory I'm not surprise however after played with batch size I'm a little confused how the GPU memory is managed.

I was able to evaluate the model with a batch size 2500 however I'm confused about how many memory is used and how TF/python/numpy manage it.

I choose a batch of 2750 I wasn't able to evaluate the model.. How can I get an estimate of how much memory will I need?

Comment: this could be useful https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12649/how-to-calculate-the-mini-batch-memory-impact-when-training-deep-learning-models

Comment: Note: if you're looking at the GPU memory consumption in your experiments, wondering why the value doesn't seem to change with the batch size, read [this section of the Tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/using_gpu#allowing_gpu_memory_growth) that explains why that is the case and how to avoid it (by enabling memory growth).

Comment: @GPhilo link is dead.

Comment: @KevinJohnsrude Now the guide is here: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu#allowing_gpu_memory_growth